# Capturing video from a webcam in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Other than DirectShow, what are the other options? I want to use this in an instant messaging application currently under development.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at opencv. It has support for capturing live-streams from webcams.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Answer (score 0):

The pre-DirectShow API was [Video for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713492%28VS.85%29.aspx), I guess it's still going to work, Windows tends to favor backwards-compatibility quite heavily. There might be problems with driver support though, sometimes hardware manufacturers don't enjoy supporting multiple API:s too much. I'm not sure if the different API:s require different drivers, though.

Comment: I believe it shouldn't matter too much. Even though we have .Net the win32 api still works for exemple. DirectShow is built using whatever API was there before. If DirectShow is too work than the older API has to work. That is what I believe anyways. Although DirectShow might have been completely rewritten from scratch and not depend on the older API.